# Does it matter how many unrollings are used in an LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

I can't see why the number of unrollings, i.e., the number of time steps considered at once during training or prediction, would be very important in an LSTM. Whether the number of unrollings/timesteps is 1 or 100, the LSTM state is mutated at every time step. Is this merely like the difference between stochastic gradient descent vs. minibatch gradient descent in a regular feedforward neural net?

- Suppose that you have 100,000 ordered training examples. You could train them one example at a time, in order.
- Suppose that at prediction time, you have a "sentence" (for example) with 10 words and you want to predict the 11th word. You could either feed the 10 words to the LSTM at once in the unrolled network, or you could feed the LSTM one word at a time and then observe the prediction that follows the 10th word. I suspect that the one-example-at-a-time network would be problematic if we're trying to predict the next word for sentences of different lengths (because ideally we would reset the SHORT-term memory between predictions for different sentences) but I am very hazy on this and would appreciate any insight from the answerer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unrolling is only defined for **training**. During evaluation there is no such thing as an unrolling, you just feed in data and keep the hidden state. However, for training, it has a **huge** effect. To better understand this, let's take a look at the following diagram with unroll 3.

```
                       UPDATE
                          |
                          v
LSTM_t-LSTM_t+1-LSTM_t+2     LSTM_t+3-LSTM_t+4-LSTM_t+5 .... 
 |      |        |            |        |        |
x_t    x_t+1    x_t+2        x_t+3    x_t+4    x_t+5
```

during backpropagation, there is **no** signal between LSTM<sub>t+3</sub> and LSTM<sub>t+2</sub>, because parameters used in the forward loop have already been updated. In order to have a "flow" of information from LSTM<sub>t+3</sub> and LSTM<sub>t+2</sub> you would have to store x<sub>t+2</sub> in memory to be able to compute the partial derivatives, but then there is no flow to LSTM<sub>t+1</sub>, so you need x<sub>t+1</sub> in memory as well, and so on. On the other hand, long unroll might make gradient flow difficult and thus cause problems.

This is a much bigger issue than just deciding on the batch size: here you are actually dealing with lack of learning signal in one case, and possibly much harder training in the other. Furthermore, in many applications, you simply cannot unroll till the end of the sequence, since some sequences are potentially infinite, or one needs to actually do other stuff with the model (like in RL, where on one hand one fits the model, but, on the other you use the very same model to gather new data).

Comment: So the benefit of n>1 unrollings is the error propagation through multiple time steps. Backpropagation updates are easy to understand for a vanilla feedforward network; there is a hiearchy of representations that get updated. LSTM updates are harder to understand... it is a temporal hierarchy and I need to read the original LSTM paper to see precisely what gets updated and whether temporal patterns are somehow stored.

Comment: yes, without the unrolling you have a problem with lack of "synchronization" you update with 1 step, then you no longer have the same network parameters, thus you would need to recalculate all the internal activations on **previous** data points to be able to backprop error from the current timestep.